# UITableView add cell Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, animation

Can any one help me out with `UITableView` animating issue?

By default we have animation for deleting cell and reordering cells in `UITableView`.

Can we have animated adding cell, if so how to do it.

I have checked out **Three20**, did not not get how `twitter` has done the table expand animation under **MyProfile>ReTweets**.

Want to try it without `Three20 frameowrk,` using the existing animation in `UITableView`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the following UITableView method:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Example with self.dataSource being a mutable array and your table only having 1 section:

```
[self.dataSource addObject:@"New Item"];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.dataSource count]-1 inSection:0];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Note: Subtracted 1 from datasource count since NSIndexPath is zero indexed.

Comment: thanks for the code, can u give me a working sample ? o
I am slightly confused with how to update the data source while doing the insertion.

Comment: earlier I would be simply adding a record to data source (NSMutableArray) and calling [self.tableView reloadData];
But that would not animatedly bring in the new element .

Comment: just a small change in ur code @JK

plz edit your answer , hope it helps some one looking for this kind of solution.

[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.dataSource count] inSection:0],nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

Comment: Do not forger to surround with `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]`

Comment: Rows are enumerated from 0, so new index = self.dataSource.count will cause an exception, it should be `NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.dataSource.count -1 inSection:0];`. @Run Loop please edit your answer

Answer (score 23):

## Swift

Example array that is the data source for the table view

```
var myArray = ["Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
```

The following will add a row with animation at the top of the table view.

```
// add item to current array
myArray.insert("Horse", atIndex: 0)

// insert row in table
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

**Multiple updates**

If you need to do multiple insertions and/or deletions then surround them with `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([addIndexPath1, addIndexPath2, ...], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath1, deleteIndexPath2, ...], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Further reading**

- [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

Comment: I am using your code to insert the rows i need inserted however, no matter what animation type i pick it always animates in the same way (i.e fade, botom ,left, all have the same behaviour). Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis, I haven't worked on this for a while so I don't know. I'll put it on my list of things to check out, but I might not get to it for a while. If you figure it out first, please leave another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

i hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

In swift is also possible using:

```
func insertRow(entries: [String]) {
    tableView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: entries.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .bottom)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```