# UITableView modify only one header section after delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a UITableView with more section "closed". When I tap on a section, with a workaround, I make the section explode showing the rows for that section. The problem that I have is that I have to animate the header to collapse it to an half of its width.

This is the code I'm using

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Sport *sport = [self.sportList objectAtIndex:section];

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tableView.frame.size.width, SECTION_HEIGHT)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:31.0/255.0 green:59.0/255.0 blue:143.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *sportTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, tableView.frame.size.width, SECTION_HEIGHT-4)];
    sportTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [headerView addSubview:sportTitle];

    UIButton *sportButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
    [sportButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sportButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sportButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    sportButton.tag = section;
    [headerView addSubview:sportButton];

    return headerView;
}
```

This is the selector:

```
-(void)didSelectedButton:(UIButton *)_button
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedSport:)])
    {
        [self.delegate didSelectedSport:sport];
    }
}
```

The delegate updates only the dataSource and calls the `reloadData`, making possible the explosion/collapse of the sections. But now I want to animate the changes to the width of the header for that section, is it possible? Thanks

**EDIT:** I can modify the header using the property `superview` of the UIButton in the selector, but I have to do it after the controller drew it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122934/uitableview-add-cell-animation

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for. I know how to insert rows, I did it yet. My problem is to animate the headerView of the section after the tableview drew it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function below. Set your superview of uibutton as the from view in the method.
Create another view with your needed width and set it as to view in the method. Give a animation of choice in options.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:from
                    toView:to
                  duration:.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
```